# Return a map with file sizes using a lambda expression and a regular expression java

Tags: java, regex, java-stream

How to return a map with the size of files in the specified directory whose names match the specified mask. A DOS mask can contain special characters ' * ' and '?'.

My code:

```
public Map<Path, Long> fileSizes(Path dir, String mask, boolean recursive) throws IOException {
    return Files.walk(dir)
            .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
            .filter( x -> x.toFile().getName().equals(mask))
            How to make a filter by mask and regular expression correctly? Where to insert "regex"?
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Path::getFileName, (x) -> x.toFile().length()));
}
}
```

And if you know, tell me the correct regular expression. I made this expression: "(?:(?:*)?(?:\w+))|(?:(?:\?)(?:\w))"

Comment: Instead of a regular expression, [create a single PathMatcher](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher%28java.lang.String%29) before invoking Files.walk.  Then use `.filter(pathMatcher::matches)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to combine VGR's excellent suggestion and your slightly tweaked code we're getting something like that:

```
public Map<Path, Long> fileSizes(Path dir, String mask, boolean recursive) throws IOException {
    PathMatcher pathMatcher = dir.getFileSystem().getPathMatcher("glob:" + mask);
    return Files.walk(dir, recursive ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : 1)
            .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
            .filter(path -> pathMatcher.matches(path.getFileName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Path::getFileName,
                    path -> {
                        try {
                            return Files.size(path);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                        }
                    }
            ));
}
```

The ugliest part here is handling `IOException` inside lambda...

Comment: And if you process IOException from the outside or do not process it at all?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do that. `toMap` accepts an instance of `Function<Path, Long>` as a second argument. It's an interface with method `Long apply(Path t);` so its implementation is not allowed to throw any checked exceptions. If you wouldn't handle `IOException` inside that lambda, code will not compile at all. Checked exceptions and Java 8 functional API is not compatible, you have to process checked exception or convert it into unchecked exception inside the lambda and it looks ugly. Even standard library does that.

Answer (score 0):

With this implementation, there may be problems?

```
public Map<Path, Long> fileSizes(Path dir, String mask, boolean recursive) throws IOException {
    final PathMatcher pathMatcher = dir.getFileSystem().getPathMatcher("glob:**/*" + mask + "*");

    try (final Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(dir, recursive ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : 1)) {
        return stream.filter(pathMatcher::matches)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Path::getFileName, (x) -> x.toFile().length()));
    }
}
```